# Clear data exiting browser

Tags: durandal

I am using Durandal. When i load page for first time, then i load grid and fill the data. Select something from grid and display details. Now i exit the browser and again come back using the same link. Then i can see that it reloads the old data which was selected last time before exiting browser. I want to clear that data when browser is closed. I tried creating deactivate function  and return back to viewmodel

```
function deactivate(){
 // clean up code
}
```

But i dont know where exactly to call this function to clear the data. Or is there any other way to do it?

**Update1**

Sorry i meant the data is remembered not when closing browser but if i naviagate to some other page on website and then again come back to same page.

Comment: How are you declaring the module that seems to be "remembering" the data, as a singleton or as an instance?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you try this!

Click&Clean allows you to Clear Browsing Data when chrome closes, you can add this feature to your browser at Google Chrome Gallery: 
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod!

if you clear manually all the cache and history then also you not able seen your previous page. that may be depend upon browser not a your website program!

Comment: No i dont want any external program for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function with a signature of "deactivate" to your viewmodel and Durandal will call this function with built-in functionality when the view is deactivated (Source: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks). Within that function you'll want to set the observable holding your data to undefined.

```
define([],
function () {

    var vm = {
        //#region Initialization.        
        activate: activate,
        attached: attached,
        deactivate: deactivate,
        //#endregion

        //#region Properties.
        data: ko.observable(),
        //#endregion

        //#region Methods.
        //#endregion
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal methods.
    function activate() {
        return true;
    }

    function attached() {
        // Fetch your data.
        return true;
    }

    function deactivate() {
        vm.data(undefined);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

Comment: I tried using deactivate but its not calling. Do i need to include something special to make it call?

Comment: You need to make sure the deactivate function is accessible from your viewmodel. If you make a jsFiddle I can take a look.